# How to implement 1-way SSL in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-security

I am building a middle tier which will consume information from multiple downstream systems. The ask is to talk to them over 1 way SSL. I looked up samples but this concept is a bit if a mystery to me. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean with 1 way SSL? If you mean SSL where traffic only flows into one direction (i.e. unidirectional) then this is impossible since the SSL handshake requires bidirectional communication. If you instead mean that only the server gets authenticated (i.e. contrast to mutual authentication) then this is just the normal SSL and there are numerous examples on how to do this. If you are failing to understand the concepts then describe clearly what exactly you don't understand since it makes no sense to add another example and you'll fail to understand it again.

Comment: See [One was SSL with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292012/spring-boot-one-way-ssl-forces-key-store-configuration-on-client-side/59657074#59657074)

Answer (score 0):

The question is too vague IMHO, I'll try to provide general insights

The answer may vary depending on the actual requirements in your organization security department and your actual spring boot configuration.

Spring Boot is a Java framework that usually allows the deployment architecture with an embedded tomcat, jetty or undertow servers that serve Http endpoints exposed by Spring MVC or without an embedded server at all (usually for legacy deployments)
If you in a "legacy" mode (build a WAR) - then HTTPs configuration should be done on the actual server and not in spring boot application.

If you use an embedded server, then the actual technical solution can actually depend on the server you use underneath, at least to some extent.

Indeed like Steffen Ullrich has stated in the comment section, there are many examples of doing this.

For example, take a look at [This one](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-boot/spring-boot-ssl-https-example/)

If you want to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPs you should configure your server to do so, and this solution is Tomcat specific.

Another thing to consider is whether you want to use SSL at the level of spring boot at all. Maybe you're running under the gateway / some kind of proxy. In this case, it can make sense to use https for accessing the proxy from outside, but from a proxy to java application you could use HTTP.

I know I'm just speculating about this solution, I've just decided to mention it because in my experience there are many organizations that work like this.

In addition, since spring boot is used for microservice development, the chances are that you have many spring boot artifacts that somehow "talk" to each other, so maybe running HTTPs between them is redundant.