# Spring Boot: One-way SSL forces key store configuration on client side

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

Let me preface this with the fact that Java security is not an area I'm well versed in.

I have a number of Spring Boot services that communicate via REST calls. When I configure to use SSL/HTTPS, I need to provide access and configuration for various certificate files and related information. Currently, we are doing only one-way verification. Two-way verification may come at a later time.

My understanding of how this works for *one-way verification* is that the client has access to a trust store that contains public key information about any servers that it will interact with. A given server will have a key store containing its key information (I assume both public and private). When the client attempts to invoke a server, there is some key information exchanged between the two and the client verifies whether the server's key information is contained in its trust store. If so, all is good and the process proceeds. If not, the call is rejected. I am also under the impression that the client needs no key store information, since it will not be called by anything.

When I configure the services to use SSL, I need to set a number of SSL properties, like the following:

```
server:
  port: <some port>
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    protocol: TLS
    trust-store-type: JKS
    trust-store: classpath:server.truststore
    trust-store-password: <password>
    key-store-type: JKS
    key-store: classpath:server.keystore
    key-store-password: <password>
    key-alias: <alias>
```

The above is an example for a server service. On a slight tangent, I would think that a "server" service that never calls anything else, would have no need for the trust store information.

For a client service that is never called by anything, I would think that I should be able to leave out the key store related information. Something like the following:

```
server:
  port: <some port>
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    protocol: TLS
    trust-store-type: JKS
    trust-store: classpath:server.truststore
    trust-store-password: <password>
```

Obviously it needs the trust store information, but I think should not need any key store information, since it's not needed.

I am not allowed to do this, however. If I attempt to leave out the key store properties, the application will fail complaining that it cannot load key store 'null'. The Spring Boot application startup process seems to require key store properties to be specified if SSL is enabled, regardless of whether it's needed.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: 1. Define 'client service'. If it's a service, it's a server, and an SSL server needs a keystore. 2. If it's never called why does it need a configuration? Why does it even exist?

Comment: Client service: A `@Service` annotated application that makes a REST call to another `@Service` annotated application (server). Regarding question 2, that may a good point - maybe I don't need the `server.ssl.*` config.

Comment: Regarding your first item - why does a service (or server, if you like) *need* a keystore? I can see why it would need a trust store when making a REST call to another service, but if nothing calls it, what is going to be requesting the keystore information? Keep in mind I'm doing one-way verification.

Comment: So I experimented with having a client without any `server.ssl.*` configuration. The "server" service is fully configured for SSL. The problem I have here is a protocol exception because the server expects https, while the client is using http in its URL.

Comment: A server needs a keystore because, unless you make special provision, the enabled TLS cipher suites require server authentication, for which it needs a private key and a certificate in a keystore.

Answer (score 0):

One way ssl with Spring Boot app as a consumer for example a REST service consumer, only trust store is required to be set up no need for the key store as per the PKI infrastructure. However if you choose to use application.properties to specify the trust store, you have to specify a key store as well, bit bizarre, but there is a work around if you are ok to specify the trust store in the code using the following two piece of code anywhere

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", new File("YourTrustStore.jks").getAbsolutePath() );
```

To create a trust store using keytool

```
keytool -keystore YourTrustStore.jks -alias MyCA -import -file C:/temp/ca.cer
```